# jQuery live submit caugth in infinite loop

Tags: submit, form-submit, infinite-loop, jquery

I'm trying to submit a form using jQuery and it worked just fine until I had to add a confirmation window so users can review their data before submission, here's the code:

```
$("#create-group-form").live('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    jConfirm('Here I display the group info...', 'Confirm Group', function(r){
        if ( r ) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

I'm using the jAlert plugin for jQuery but it works just as a regular Confirm prompt with different styling, the preblem is that when users click Ok on the prompt it goes again into the live submit getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Is there a way to stop it from going in again this event after I confirm? I think I can unbind it somehow but I haven't found a way to do it successfully.

BTW I'm using live submit because the form is in a modal window.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a modal window, so what? once the DOM is ready the element is as well and you can bind the submit event - even if the form isn't displayed...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call the form element's `submit` method, rather than the jQuery selection's one.  This means the jQuery handler won't be triggered:

```
$("#create-group-form").live('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = this; // <-- this line changed
    jConfirm('Here I display the group info...', 'Confirm Group', function(r){
        if ( r ) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried it but then it redirects me to the form's action but the data doesn't get submitted :(

Comment: Nevermind, this worked the problem was that I was manipulating some data before insertion in another submit handle and since the native bypasses this the data wasn't getting cleaned and hence not inserted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: it's important you call the DOM element's `submit` and not the jQuery Object's

Answer (score 1):

This will unbind your event handler before you call `submit()` on it again.

```
$("#create-group-form").live('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    jConfirm('Here I display the group info...', 'Confirm Group', function(r){
        if ( r ) {
            form.unbind('submit');
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @javiervd Alternatively, include a variable that is modified on submit that determines if the confirm is shown again.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the submit button on the form with a `button` tag with an ID like `#psuedo-submit`. When `#psuedo-submit` is clicked, pop the modal window up and do an actual submit on confirmation.