# How to delay submit() event until after Geocoder is finished?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery, google-sheets

I'm working on a Google Maps / Google Spreadsheet mashup.

At this point I'm working on a javascript/jquery bit that allows users to fill out a form, then submits that form to a Google Spreadsheet.

When the user clicks "submit", the script will quickly send off the user's street address to Google's Geocoder, which returns the equivalent lat and lng.

The problem I'm running into is that the form information gets submitted to Google Spreadsheets *before* my Geocoder routine is complete. I can't figure out how to modify the .submit() event to keep it from submitting until after I have the lat and lng.

In my jQuery ready handler I have this:

```
    $("#ss-form").submit(function(event) {
        var street    = $('#entry_1').val();
        var citystate = $('#entry_2').val();
        var country   = $('#entry_3').val();
        findAddress(street,citystate,country);              
    });
```

It is calling this function:

```
function findAddress(street, citystate, country) {
    var myAddress = [
        street,
        citystate.toLowerCase(),
        country.toLowerCase()
    ].join(', ');

    geocoder.geocode(
        {address: myAddress}, 
        function(result,status) {
            var myLat = result[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var myLng = result[0].geometry.location.lng();
            $('#entry_5').val(myLat);
            $('#entry_6').val(myLng);
            console.log(myLat+','+myLng);
        }
    );
}
```

The relevant HTML is a simple form with six inputs (#entry_0 through #entry_6).

So what I want to do is get the Lat and Lng, then put them into the HTML form as values, and THEN let the form submit. How do I get the submission to delay until after the findAddress function is finished?

Comment: Here's an example page, which incorporates one of the answers given below: http://www.joshrenaud.com/pd/testcase/google-maps-spreadsheet-test.html

Comment: When I try it in Chrome, the console shows the same output repeated several times until it 'Cannot read property '0' of null'. I am still learn JS, but it seems to my ignorant mind like the submit() call within findAddress is causing it to make an infinite loop.

Comment: On the one hand, I would like to make this work with the submit handler. I know the user is finished with their information once they click Submit, and it makes sense to look for LatLng at that point. But given the trouble i'm having getting it to work, I may just move the LatLng lookup to a focus event on the form's input fields. Any time a field gets focus, check to see if all the address fields are complete. If so, run the LatLng check. Then the LatLng data will be ready before the Submit button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ss-form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent the submit
        var street    = $('#entry_1').val();
        var citystate = $('#entry_2').val();
        var country   = $('#entry_3').val();
        findAddress(street,citystate,country,$(this));        

    });
```

submit the form in the function

```
function findAddress(street, citystate, country, form ) {
    var myAddress = [
        street,
        citystate.toLowerCase(),
        country.toLowerCase()
    ].join(', ');

    geocoder.geocode(
        {address: myAddress}, 
        function(result,status) {
            var myLat = result[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var myLng = result[0].geometry.location.lng();
            $('#entry_5').val(myLat);
            $('#entry_6').val(myLng);
            console.log(myLat+','+myLng);

            form[0].submit(); //submit the form here  
        }
    );

}
```

Comment: This will not work as findAddress() triggers an asynchronous request (which is the route of his problem), so that request will start, then the submit will be triggered. Your code will behave identically to how the code currently behaves.

Comment: still won't work. You need to move the `form.submit()` inside of the callback of the geocoder. I've updated it to what it should be.

Comment: Both this approach and the one below seem to be causing infinite loops when I try them. I'm going to put up a test page and add a comment with the link to my question about.

Comment: oh yeah, didn't think about that. Calling the submit function, will re-trigger the submit handler... :/

Comment: @Kirkman14: Have a look at the answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843277/jquery-live-submit-caugth-in-infinite-loop). It shows how to fix this infinite loop. I've also updated the above answer to fix the issue. Selecting the raw HTML element (using `[0]`) and calling its submit method, will not retrigger the jQuery handler.

Comment: I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function" when I try that.

Comment: Before submiting the form inside the geocoder, you should unbind the 'submit' event so that you don't trigger an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$("#ss-form").submit(function(event) {
     if(!$(this).data("geocodeset")){
        findAddress();              
        return false;
     }
});

function findAddress() {
    var $form = $("#ss-form");
    var street    = $('#entry_1').val();
    var citystate = $('#entry_2').val();
    var country   = $('#entry_3').val();

    var myAddress = [
        street,
        citystate.toLowerCase(),
        country.toLowerCase()
    ].join(', ');

    geocoder.geocode(
        {address: myAddress}, 
        function(result,status) {
            var myLat = result[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var myLng = result[0].geometry.location.lng();
            $('#entry_5').val(myLat);
            $('#entry_6').val(myLng);
            console.log(myLat+','+myLng);

            $form.data("geocodeset", true).submit(); 
        }
    );

}
```

Comment: you may need to update your signature of `findAddress()` in the submit handler. It doesn't match what you've got the function.

Comment: Please see my comment above. I posted an example page which incorporates your answer, but it's not working.

Comment: @Kirkma14 - geocoder result is null and result[0] is null so you are getting js exception on that line. Now you need to find out why geocoder is giving null response.

Comment: The geocoder gives null only after it has looped through about 20 times. Your solution creates an infinite loop. I added a counter just to be certain.

Comment: Why will my solution create an infinite loop? I just added the code to submit the form in geocoder callback method.

Comment: I'm a JS novice, so maybe I am misunderstanding what's going on. But it seems to me that $form.submit() triggers the submit handler again (as Alastair points out above). So it is looping through that submit handler over and over until (presumably) the browser kills it.

Comment: I see, it is because of sumbit handler calling itself now I have modified the code. Can you check my edited answer?

Comment: Okay, with your code, there are no errors or infinite loops. When I click the submit button, the code checks the LatLng properly. But the form does *not* get submitted. If I click the button a _second_ time, then it *does* get submitted.

Comment: Same as with Alistair's version above, I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function" when I try it with [0] added to $form.

Comment: What is `#ss-form`? Is it a `submit` button?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2672/discussion-between-kirkman14-and-shankarsangoli)